# Possible to use custom SSL or TCP/IP packets to detect VPN use?

Tags: tls, vpn, threat-mitigation

What custom TCP/IP packets or other statistics can I use to detect VPN usage?

I understand that this may generate a number of false positives, but my goal is to focus analysis on certain types of traffic.

Possible examples include:

- Browser reports geolocation doesn't match expected latency to that site is much higher than expected
- Ping with the DF set
- Custom packet size + MTU tests
- SSL protocol features (spdy? fido?)

I'm mostly interested in using SSL/TCP/IP/ICMP to detect such connections... as opposed to  browser-DNS leaks, flash, or other approaches, but think other people may find it interesting if you have such a non TCP based detection method.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to probe remotely to see if a VPN is in use or you want to perform analysis on traffic as it passes through your network?

Comment: @raz I am a web host (or socket server) that wants to detect intentional violations of copyright, but using VPNs to access material outside of designated locations.

Comment: @LamonteCristo off-topic, but if the person paid for it (or has acquired the rights to view the content) then how is it a violation of copyright ? It's because of restrictions like these that pirate sites are successful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can look at connections and, by inspecting the packets, determine that a VPN is in use. VPNs are meant to look like regular connections.

The only solution I know of is one that blacklists IP addresses belonging to known VPN providers. That can be used effectively though it is a bit of an arms race as VPN providers try to get new addresses all the time to encourage the exact type of usage you are trying to prevent. [This thread](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/2980/hulu-is-now-detecting-pia-vpn-access) is an example of what happened when Hulu got the user's VPN IPs on a blacklist.

Even if you use a blacklisting service, you won't be able to identify all VPNs, especiallly if users run their own [VPN on a VPS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/45101).

Sorry that I don't know of any blacklisting services to recommend but you should be able to find them in Google.